# Declarative Jenkins Pielines to run a command before SCM checkout

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

Need to run a command before git checkout starts through pipeline code. It is similar to using **Run buildstep before SCM runs**. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

You need to use the options at the beginning to prevent it doing the default checkout first and then trigger the checkout after your initial steps that you wish to do beforehand.

So in your pipeline script declare you agent/tools installations/environment vars then use

```
options {
    skipDefaultCheckout true
}
```

Then do your pre steps in a stage e.g.

```
stage('Preparation') {
     steps {
          //Insert steps here
     }
}
```

Your next stage should then do the checkout that you stopped earlier. This is really simple

```
stage('Checkout') {
    steps {
         checkout scm
    }
}
```

Then you can continue your normal steps. Took me a while to find this solution also. I use this to check out another repo first and read it's tag to generate combined version numbers.

Comment: I can't version control this pipeline if I use `skipDefaultCheckout true`. Is that right?

Comment: Thank you very much!
This piece of information was what I needed to ascend out of some rabbit-hole :)
On a side-note: because of the `skipDefaultCheckout` option, you'd need to apply `checkout scm` at the beginning of all your stages if you want to otherwise reproduce the behaviour before introducing the option.

Answer (score 0):

Put pipeline code directly in jenkins instead of fetching it from git, do in first stage what you need do and start git checkout in the second stage